# Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

Help? I don't know why I am getting this error. I am getting at in line 39:

```
term[1] = differentiate(Coeff[1], exponent[1]);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Full code listing:

```
public class Calcprog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numTerms = 7;
        double[] Coeff = new double[6];
        double[] exponent = new double[6];
        String[] term = new String[6];

        System.out.println("Enter the number of terms in your polynomial:");
        numTerms = input.nextInt();

        while (numTerms > 6) {
            if (numTerms > 6) {
                System.out.println("Please limit the number of terms to six.");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of terms in your polynomial:");
                numTerms = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < numTerms + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the coefficient of term #" + i + " in decimal form:");
            Coeff[i] = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the exponent of term #" + i + " in decimal form:");
            exponent[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        term[1] = differentiate(Coeff[1], exponent[1]);
    }

    public String differentiate(int co, int exp) {
        double newco, newexp;
        String derivative;
        newexp = exp - 1;
        newco = co * exp;
        derivative = Double.toString(newco) + "x" + Double.toString(newexp);
        return derivative;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to pass double arguments to a method that accepts ints, which requires a casting that may result in loss of information.

You can make it work by an explicit cast :

```
term[1] = differentiate((int)Coeff[1], (int)exponent[1]);
```

Or you can change your `differentiate` method to accept double arguments, which would probably make more sense :

```
public String differentiate(double co, double exp)
```

Answer (score 1):

your method is not static, and you calling in the main which is static, remember a non static method can be access direct in a static method, you have to create an instance of the class to access that method, and also the parameter you are passing is `double` and not `int`. Your method should be like that `public static String differentiate(double co, double exp){`

Answer (score 0):

change the argument types of the differentiate method to double. This should then look as follows

```
  public String differentiate(double co, double exp){
    ...
  }
```