# incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int (high school hw)

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I am taking a high school class and I need help. I am getting the error mentioned in the title. here is my code (i am supposed to make random numbers for people to guess where a zero is and i need to let them know if theyre close to it and how close theyre)

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class p5g
    {
        public static void main(String[] arg)
        {
            String width = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many rows do you     want?");        
            String length = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many columns do you want?");
        int lol = Integer.parseInt( width );
        int wow = Integer.parseInt( length );
        int[][]gameBoard = new int[lol][wow];

        int[] nums = new int[lol*wow];
        for(int i =0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
             nums[i]=(int)100*Math.random();
        }

        String row = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a row");        
        String col = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a column");
        int ro = Integer.parseInt( row );
        int co = Integer.parseInt( col );

    }
}
```

Comment: What line of code is causing the error?

Comment: in the for loop  nums[i]=(int)100*Math.random();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173575/incompatible-types-possible-lossy-conversion-from-double-to-int)

Comment: Why not using the Random class itself? It has a #nextInt method. Also, if you want to include boundaries, check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values.

Answer (score 1):

The `Math.random` will return a double

so rather than casting to an `int` try

```
new Double (100*Math.random()).intValue ();
```

Comment: thanks, this worked (i have no idea what you just did b/c my teacher didnt teach us .intValue() but thanks again)

Comment: Jacob, have a look at the javadocs for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Comment: @jacobOlivares123 If you are happy with my answer please consider to accept and/or upvote - Thanks